# editing a process' text segment in an exe(c++)

Tags: c++, winapi

So I am trying to mod a game and I have to translate the strings in the exe file. Modifying a d3d9 wrapper to change the strings in memory during the process instead of editing the exe directly has been working for me, until I found a string in which the translated text would be 1 byte longer than the original string. So I have to move the next string by 1 byte. The string's address is 0x517468 in the .rdata segment. I found an asm code on the .text segment.

```
PUSH 00517468 //'0x68 0x68 0x74 0x51' in hex
```

So I can overwrite my string to 0x517469. 0x517468 will be a 0x00 null. however I cannot find a way to change the asm code in the code block above to PUSH 00517469. I've tried using VirtualProtectEx() and WriteProcessMemory() but no luck. here is my current code.

```
void editasm(int hex,char* targetstr) {
    char* buffer = reinterpret_cast<char*>((uint64_t)GetModuleHandleA(NULL) + 0x0002c5ef);//this would be 0042c5ee, which is where the above asm code is located.
    char* myStr = targetstr;// this is '0x68 0x69 0x74 0x51'
    size_t strlength = strlen(myStr) + 1;
    DWORD oldProtect;
    VirtualProtectEx(GetModuleHandleA(NULL), buffer, strlength, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldProtect);
    int r = WriteProcessMemory(GetModuleHandleA(NULL), buffer, myStr, strlength, NULL);
    Log() << r;
    VirtualProtectEx(GetModuleHandleA(NULL),buffer, strlength, oldProtect, NULL);
    return;}
```

so the WriteProcessMemory() only returns 0, and trying ReadProcessMemory() instead also returns 0.

Comment: Did you check the MSDN on error handling? Also, this has very little to do with C++ but a lot to do with the Windows API, add that tag.  As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Does VirtualProtectEx succeed? What errors are returned? When you step through the code in your debugger, are the pointer values correct?

Comment: You could subtract N bytes from the pointer that points to the asm code you provided and overwrite the values there.